# To add extra key-value pairs to an array in php makes JSONException prompt while parsing in Android side

Tags: php, android

Generally, I post a requet to PHP server to query a mysql table's data set and then it will send back to Andorid to parsing the resonse string(a JSONArray string) without problem. The PHP code section used is  as below:

```
....
if($result = mysql_query($sql, $link))
{
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) 
    {   
      while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
      {
          $data[]=$row;
      }
    }
}

print_r(urlencode(json_encode($data))); 
if (is_resource($result)) 
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);
```

However, if I add one more pars of key-value string to $data array after completing sql query by using the method in php code below:

```
$data['new_key'] = "new_value";
```

There will have the JSONArry Exception prompt in android side while parsing the new JSONArray String: ..... (The value part is double bytes' Chinese Characters)

```
Value {"new_key":"new_value","0":{"old_key1":"old_value1" ,"old_key2":"old_value2","old_key3":"old_value3",.....}} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

If you don't mind, please help and point me out where I was wrong and how to solve it, thanks !

Comment: This is probably related to the fact that you're treating $data as a sequential array and then an associative array.  Could you post the code that parses it on the android side?

Comment: at which line you are putting  $data['new_key'] = "new_value";

Comment: Thanks for jjm ! And the final $data array was encoded as JSONArray in PHP side before post to Android. Then Android parses the JSONArray String  and the error prompted.

Comment: Thanks for Akki, the code $data['new_key'] = "new_value";  was added after the while loop completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data[]['new_key'] = "new_value";
```

Also I think you need to remove the print_r and replace it with echo:

```
echo urlencode(json_encode($data));
```

(You can also remove the urlencode by the way.)

Comment: Thanks woozy ! First I follows your suggestion change the code. Android parse the JSONArray is OK without error. However, Another JSONException prompted as: org.json.JSONException: No value for new_key. From the Log of reponse string shonw on the LogCat, the JSONArray string is look like this: {"old_key1":"old_value1" ,"old_key2":"old_value2","old_key3":"old_value3",.....},{"new_key":"new_value"}]. Look at the end of the string, the new key/value pair was located in the separated bracket that makes it can not be detected and parsing by JSONObject method. Thanks again for futher comment !

Comment: Humm... I thaught you wanted to create a JSNON array like that one. If you don't want you should use: $data[0]['new_key'] = "new_value" instead.

Comment: Thanks for woozy again ! follows your suggestion,  I used "$data[0]['new_key'] = "new_value";" instead. And there is not Exception prompting... its WORLK !